# socket.io dentro do express.js ou vise versa

Tags: node.js

Como faco para colocar os sockets dentro de um post do express?

Preciso identificar um connect dendo da sessão do express

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 

        ...............

        });     

});
```

dessa maneira ele nao executa o socke.io

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi direito o problema, você precisa que a cada post "/login" seja emitido uma mensagem para o listener "connection" ?

Se for este o problema você precisa iniciar o listener "connection" independente do Express.

Após o post do login realizar um emit ou então utilizar o próprio socket.io como meio de comunicação entre client/server.